# Empty FQL query response but graph api return data

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

When I make such FQL query

select uid,first_name,last_name,about_me,birthday_date,current_location,education,friend_count,interests,pic_square,profile_url,sex,significant_other_id,subscriber_count,username,website,work,likes_count,hometown_location from user where uid IN (424073604327374)

I have empty response

{"data": []}

http://d.pr/i/bnKi

But when I try to get same user with Graph API I have not empty response

http://d.pr/i/yns